# Spring WebInitializer with Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) on Openshift

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, openshift

I try to **deploy** **spring** **application** on Openshift. It works just fine on my local machine running under **Tomcat 7.0.32**, but it fails under the Openshift's  **Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)** with the following **error**:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configuration.SecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
public void addFilters(ServletContext servletContext) {
    CharacterEncodingFilter encoding = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    encoding.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    encoding.setForceEncoding(true);
    servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", encoding)
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter())
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    servletContext
            .addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
                    new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .rememberMe().key("secretKey").and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/logout/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
}
```

}

MyWebAppInitializer:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```

}

javax.Servlet Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: From the examples I am seeing online, try adding `@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })` to your `AppConfig` class and remove `SecurityConfig.class` from your `rootContext.register()` statement. I don't know if that will work, but it is a difference that I see between yours and the examples I see online. One example can be seen here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, @LucasP! I have already had `AppConfig.class` annotated with `@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })`, so i just removed `SecurityConfig.class` from registration as you said, but it had no effect: an error is still the same. Can it be a container migration flaw, or the problem resides in my openshift's application configuration and it can be fixed somehow ?